# Typescript: getting error while using UNION operator

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using the OR operator in Typescript to define product could be either of type `ProductI` OR `CartResponseInterface.Product`

Structured as

```
product: ProductI | CartResponseInterface.Product
```

But when I am trying to get id and store it in a variable `productId` as

```
productId= product.id || product.productId
```

I get below-mentioned Errors

```
Error:1
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'ProductI | Product'.
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Product'.ts(2339)

Error2:
Property 'productId' does not exist on type 'ProductI | Product'.
Property 'productId' does not exist on type 'ProductI'.ts(2339)
```

product.model.ts

```
export interface ProductI {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
  price: number;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

cart-response.model.ts

```
export interface Product {
  productId: string;
  name: string;
  totalPrice: number;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Can someone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: show us your ProductI and CartResponseInterface.Product implementation.

Comment: updated, please check

Comment: `type X = A | B` is a *type union*, not an "OR operator".

Comment: Can you please update the product object you are using ?

Comment: @IngoBürk updated it in title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You could use [Type Assertion](https://www.javatpoint.com/typescript-type-assertion) to coerce the type and then check the product's id.

```js
const productId = (product as ProductI).id || (product as Product).productId;
// or
const productId = (<ProductI>product).id || (<Product>product).productId;
```

With that said, I wouldn't suggest doing this unless you have to. There should be a better way to utilize Typescript's types.

Answer (score -2):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-interface-inheritance

```
import "./style.css";

export interface Product {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  price: number;
}

export interface ProductI extends Product {
  customPropI?: number;
}

export interface ProductII extends Product {
  customPropII?: number;
}

const p1 = {
  id: "23",
  name: "tmep",
  price: 140,
};

const p2 = {
  id: "23",
  name: "tmep",
  price: 140,
  customPropII: 280
};

// test1
let customId = p1.id;

// test2
let customProp = null;
if((p2 as ProductI).customPropI) customProp = (p2 as ProductI).customPropI;
else if((p2 as ProductII).customPropII) customProp = (p2 as ProductII).customPropII;

const appDiv: HTMLElement = document.getElementById("app");
appDiv.innerHTML = customProp;
```

Comment: The problem with this is that `id` already exists on the object `product`, this is not replicating the OP's issue. With your example, you'd have to check for `customProp`

Comment: correct, I updated my answer. previously I would like say it is a good practice to move shared property to a parent interface, etc